# How to optimize python script to pyspark def function

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing  a pyspark program that takes a txt file and then add a few columns to the left(beginning) of the columns in the file.

My text file looks like this:

```
ID,Name,Age
1233,James,15
```

After I run the program I want it to add two columns named creation_DT and created_By to the left of the table. I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
Creation_DT,Created_By,ID,Name,Age
"current timestamp", Sean,1233,James,15
```

This code below get my required output but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this to optimize my script below using pyspark.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
with open
df = pd.read_csv("/home/path/Sample Text Files/sample5.txt", delimiter = ",")
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.insert(loc=0, column='Creation_DT', value=pd.to_datetime('today'))
df.insert(loc=1, column='Create_BY',value="Sean")
df.write("/home/path/new/new_file.txt")
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Your code uses pandas, not pyspark. What types of solution are you after here?

Comment: Pyspark. I want to convert pandas to pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is relatively easy to convert to pyspark code

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, functions as sf
import datetime
# read in using dataframe reader
# path here if you store your csv in local, should use file:///
# or use hdfs:/// if you store your csv in a cluster/HDFS.
spdf = (spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true")
.load("file:///home/path/Sample Text Files/sample5.txt"))

spdf2 = (
    spdf
    .withColumn("Creation_DT", sf.lit(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
    .withColumn("Create_BY", sf.lit("Sean"))

spdf2.write.csv("file:///home/path/new/new_file.txt")
```

this code assumes you are appending the creation_dt or create_by using the same value.

Comment: is it spdf=dataframe-... or..? cuz when i run the above code it gives my inbalid syntax error

Comment: maybe because you are using python2, type hint syntax might not be supported, I update the answer to remove the type hint

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you use any pyspark in your code, so I'll just use pandas this way:

```
cols = df.columns
df['Creation_DT'] =pd.to_datetime('today')
df['Create_BY']="Sean"
cols = cols.insert(0, 'Create_BY')
cols = cols.insert(0, 'Creation_DT') 
df.columns = cols
df.write("/home/path/new/new_file.txt")
```